# Nginx: Use different backend based on value of argument

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, proxypass

We have a legacy application written in php which we are now migrating to java.
The Application being hige, we are trying to migrate features in part.
Keeping this scenario in mind, i need to split traffic between php-fpm backend and the java app based on the value of a query string argument

for eg
if $format="csv", use fast-cgi and process request using php
If $format="xml",connect to the java backend using the proxy_pass directive.

Unfortunately i am finding it difficult to do this on nginx.

I tried the following

```
if ($args_format ="csv")
 include php;
if ($args_format ="xml")
 include proxy;
```

here php and proxy are files containing the proxy_pass and fast-cgi related statements

Unfortunately this throws a syntax error

Then I create a map by using something like

```
map $args_output $provider {
  default "proxy";
  csv      "php";
}
```

then did an 
     include $provider;

This also fails as nginx seems to load the includes at start time and not during execution of each call.

Any suggestions on how i can achieve this in an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is **$arg_format**
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_

You must use { } after if statement.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if

Try something like ...

```
if ($arg_format ="csv") {
 include php;
}
if ($arg_format ="xml") {
 include proxy;
}
```

Comment: we cannot have an include inside an if condition.If is executed at run time while an include seems to happen when the config file is being parsed.